# text on back of spinning image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code a gallery page, which contains nine pictures in a three-by-three grid. when someone clicks on an image, I want the image to spin on the Y-axis and display white text on a black background. The problem is that I don't know how to spin the image. I think it has something to do with css?

html:

```
<div id="gallery" class="gallery-section section-container type3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="indent-10">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img src="img/gallery-img-1.jpg" alt="gallery-img-1"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrapper">
                        <div class="header-wrapper">
                            <h3>
                                Rushed Flats
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="para-wrapper">
                            <p>
                                architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est
                                eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.gallery-section{
  .indent-10{
    max-width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .img-wrapper{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    img{

    }
  }
  .text-wrapper{
    .header-wrapper{
      h3{

      }
    }
    .para-wrapper{
      p{

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: The question does not contain a specific problem that needs fixing, hence it's is too broad. You don't have neither the javascript or css side implemented.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how to spin the image, nothing seems to be working

Comment: Visit the link I've provided below. It's very easy to do it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit the link below and there you will get to know about CSS 3D transitions animations etc.

https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

it will definitely help you out for the flip transition you want and lot more transition you may want to learn

Comment: Thanks for the help!